# How to get the int value of an enum in golang?

Tags: go

I have the following enum defined:

```
type MyEnum int

const (
    A MyEnum iota
    B
    C
)
```

This is embedded in a struct which I receive as a parameter from another function:

```
type Mystruct struct {
   Id string
   Type MyEnum
}
```

When I receive this struct, I want to assign the int value of the enum to another integer variable, which I need for the next steps.

For example,

```
type NewStruct struct {
   Id string
   Type int
}

NewStruct.newStruct.Id = MyStruct.mystruct.Id
NewStruct.newStruct.Type = MyStruct.mystruct.Type // gives an error saying cannot assign MyEnum to int
```

How do I assign  `0 to A, 1 to B` and do the reverse as well?

Comment: Use type conversion: `var i int; i = int(A)`